# Android Lollipop unintended options menu

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu, oncreateoptionsmenu

All of my activities have no onCreateOptionsMenu or related methods. I deleted the menu.xml and all related ones as well. I still see the options menu on the right side of the bottom bar. Any ideas why this might occur?
Min SDK is 10 and the device is Nexus 5 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `targetSdkVersion` to 11 or higher to get rid of the legacy action overflow button.

Changing `minSdkVersion` to >=11 works too, but is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Is there a way to remove it programmatically without changing the minSDK version of the app?

Comment: Just change `targetSdkVersion`, no need to touch `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: Ahh yes.. Well its kinda sad to see target SDK affects application's behavior like this. Now I can compile and run methods that require higher min SDKs. Anyway, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: That's the point of `targetSdkVersion` - to provide backwards compatibility to apps that are not tested to work with newer versions. Prior to API level 11 all devices had hardware menu button and the system needs to emulate it for apps that don't declare to target API level 11 or higher.

Comment: Yes but then why the ides allow to use methods require higher SDK then the minSDK... It is obvious that it will not work on the lower versions.

Comment: You can use whatever there is in your `compileSdkVersion`. Only call them at runtime when you've verified the device API level is high enough. Pay attention to Android Lint errors about API levels, too.